# Python error messages: AttributeError

Tags: python, function

I am getting an AttributeError in python and I cannot figure out why. I am a newb to Python so the bar is not very high for stumping me. I keep getting the error message:

> print('Name:',emp.get_emp_name())
>
> AttributeError: 'ProductionWorker' object has no attribute
>   'get_emp_name'

Here is my code:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.__name = name
        self.__number = number

    #set methods
    def set_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    def set_number(self,number):
        self.__number = number

    #get methods    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number


class ProductionWorker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, number, shift_num, pay_rate):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, number)
        self.__shift_num = shift_num
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate

    #set methods
    def set_shift_num(self,shift_num):
        self.__shift_num = shift_num
    def set_pay_rate(self,pay_rate):
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate

    #get methods    
    def get_shift_num(self):
        return self.__shift_num
    def get_pay_rate(self):
        return self.__pay_rate

def main():
    print('Please enter the following details.')
    name = input('Name:')
    number = input('Employee Number:')
    sh = input('Shift Number:')
    pay_rate = input('Pay Rate:')
    emp = ProductionWorker(name, number, sh, pay_rate)

    print('Here is the employee information:')
    print('Name:',emp.get_emp_name())
    print('Employee Number:',emp.get_emp_number())
    print('Shift Number:',emp.get_shift_num())
    print('Pay Rate:',emp.get_pay_rate())

main()
```

Comment: Probably, you should call `emp.get_name()`

Comment: add the erro to the question

Comment: Defining getters and setters is unnecessary in python.

Comment: @jordanm Isn't it still a good idea though?

Comment: @BobbyBrown No.

Comment: Why is it not a goof idea? I am no  Python expert by any means but I have seen it done in textbooks and plenty of other examples. What is the justification for not doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object can call only the methods defined in its own class definition or the method defined in its parent class.

Here, you are calling a method `get_emp_name()` which is neither defined in the class `ProductionWorker` nor in its parent class `Employee`.

You can change it to:

```
print('Name:',emp.get_name())
```

Answer (score 1):

change this two:

```
print('Name:',emp.get_emp_name())
 print('Employee Number:',emp.get_emp_number())
```

to:

```
print('Name:',emp.get_name())
 print('Employee Number:',emp.get_number())
```